# Have any anti lockdown protests been successful?

Tags: covid-19, protests, public-health

Over the past year, there have been numerous protests against Covid related lockdowns in various countries around the world. But did any of them manage to achieve their goal of convincing the government to drop restrictions?

Specifically, I’m looking for examples of governments saying something like “it would be a good idea to keep restaurants closed but the protests are now so extreme that we have to reopen them”.

Comment: No government is ever going to say that. The nearest you will get is "We utterly condemn these violent protests. And on a completely unrelated matter, we will be reopening the restaurants.

Comment: @PaulJohnson something like that would also work for the purposes of this question. Basically a government that succumbed to the will of the crowd even if they never admitted it publicly.

Comment: @JonathanReez the issue with establishing even that is the situation is so fluid. So if the government says "we are reopening the restaurants but that is not because of the protests but because the numbers are better", it might be true. Or perhaps the memories of the weighted in, even if they were not decisive.

Comment: @PaulJohnson, plenty of governments acknowledge (or admit?) that they're balancing the pandemic, the economy, and other public health issues related to the lockdown (e.g. mental stress). The difference between "extimating the exhaustion of the population" and "giving in to protest" can lie in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: A deeper issue is that lockdowns were meant to be temporary in the first place, changing as the situation on the ground changed. Since the situation on the ground has changed a lot (e.g., with the introduction of vaccines and the properties of different strains changing) you'd expect policies to change anyway and for protests to mount as the new situations on the ground made the policies most appropriate to change even in the absence of protest. So, it is tricky to unravel cause and effect.

Comment: @ohwilleke we also quickly found out that places like Florida or Sweden were doing just fine despite refusing to lockdown or mandate masks. But unfortunately governments dragged their feet all the way until summer 2022.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't disagree that it may be possible to identify cases where protests and not a change in the situation is what drove results (at least in a but for causation sense). But it is harder than it might seem.

Comment: @ohwilleke To say nothing of situations where a combination of protests and changing situations both played equal role in changing policy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like they've worked exceptionally well in... [China](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/dec/04/shanghai-scraps-covid-testing-policy-relaxation):

> **Chinese cities ease Covid curbs in wake of protests**
>
> Chinese cities, including the financial hub of Shanghai and Urumqi in
> the far west, have announced an easing of coronavirus curbs after
> unprecedented protests against zero-Covid restrictions last weekend.
>
> Urumqi, the capital of the Xinjiang region and centre of the first
> protests, will reopen malls, markets, restaurants and other venues
> from Monday, authorities said, ending months-long strict lockdowns.
>
> There was no sign of any significant unrest this weekend, although
> police were out in force in the Liangmaqiao area of Beijing and in
> Shanghai around Wulumuqi Road, which is named after Urumqi. Protests
> took place at both sites a week ago.

China can now be considered to have had the most successful anti-lockdown protests in the history of the pandemic. They've reopened the border in early January and ended every single precaution with the exception of masks.

Answer (score 5):

Germany?

It is a bit of a tricky situation because there are the federal government, 16 state governments, and even county-level officials involved, but it appears that "the government" agreed to ease lockdown measures in recent weeks despite the **personal** conviction of Chancellor Merkel that they should be kept or even increased. She didn't have the **political** capital to make that happen against a groundswell of discontent with the lockdown.

A snap lockdown over Easter seems to have failed due to [administrative challenges](https://www.dw.com/en/covid-angela-merkel-backtracks-on-easter-lockdown-after-uproar/a-56969820) -- did they declare a public holiday, or didn't they? Nobody was sure.

For that matter, look at some of the local governments in the [Erzgebirge](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore_Mountains).

Comment: Is there a correlation between which German cities had the biggest anti lockdown protests and which cities now have the least amount of restrictions?

Comment: @JonathanReez, I don't think so. It seems to be a question of infection numbers and the fortitude of the state and county governments. Leaders in a strong position can overcome protests, weak ones cannot.

Comment: I think this answer is missing the link between a (supposed) public discontent and the easing of lockdown measures. From the [surveys](https://www.tagesschau.de/inland/deutschlandtrend/deutschlandtrend-2561.html) I've [seen](https://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/corona-lockdown-mehrheit-gegen-lockerung-der-massnahmen-a-55644cf4-a696-432d-9193-000d2526d324), ~25% want easing, ~40% want the lockdown to stay as-is, and ~30% want stricter measures. So overall a majority don't want easing.

Comment: Public opinion isn't directly related to political capital (nor to the protests this question is about), but imho it's at least one data point to consider when evaluating the claim that widespread discontent in the general population is the reason for easing the lockdown.

Comment: @tim, in that case any easing of the lockdown could be interpreted as caving in to protesters. Or they get interpreted as aiming for a compromise with a significant part of the population ...

Comment: @o.m. Sure, that's one explanation. But I'm not sure that the protests are significant enough for that (the biggest one had afaik 20k protestors; there have been way bigger protests that didn't result in anything), and given the surveys, a more appropriate compromise would be to maintain the status quo. And there's other explanations as well (eg companies - which have a better lobby than protestors - pushing for openings, politicians pushing for openings - not necessarily bc of protests, but bc that's what they want, etc).

Comment: Is Germany now aiming for 100% infection rates?

Comment: @user253751, one would easily get 0% infection by closing all borders and ordering everyone to stay home for a month. The economic and humanitarian consequences would be drastic, so that is not done ...

Comment: @o.m. the economic and humanitarian consequences of targeting 100% have also been pretty bad. Worse than wave 1, where everyone was ordered to stay home for a month, I'd say

Comment: @user253751, you keep claiming that they are "targeting 100%" -- that's nonsense. The policies are far from perfect, but they try to balance the pandemic and the economy. Germany *never* had a total lockdown, they *never* had a total economic slowdown. Someone has to pay for the *Kurzarbeitergeld* all those people are getting.

Comment: @o.m. indeed, and they would have to pay less if there weren't high levels of COVID shutting down the economy. This "half lockdown" has lasted more than twice as long as the first full lockdown did!

Comment: @user253751, but do you agree that nobody is *targeting* 100% infections? At least according to most normal definitions of that verb.

Comment: @o.m. It's the implicit target if you don't do anything to make it not happen, and they are not doing anything to make it not happen. I can walk around Berlin and see plenty of social gatherings.

Comment: @user253751, the typical German term for that would be "billigend in Kauf genommen" -- tacitly accepted, not aimed for.

Comment: btw, the [most recent](https://www.zdf.de/nachrichten/politik/corona-politbarometer-lockerungen-100.html#xtor=CS5-62) surveys show an even stronger support for more measures (36% support stricter measures, 31% as-is, 26% less strict; it attributes the wrong view that the public is against measures not to protests, but to lobbying by business associations)

Comment: @user253751 My aneddoctical impression from reading German media and talking with friends living there is that Berlin has an unusually high support for easing of measures, and that the local administration is among the ones most opposed to the "Notbremse". Here in Bavaria it's quite different (although there are definite signs of tiredness with the lockdown here as well)

Comment: @DenisNardin, that changes week by week and measure by measure.

Answer (score 3):

As of last week (I'm writing this March 29th), the provincial government of BC, Canada is planning to [relax indoors attendance to religious events](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/religious-gatherings-bc-spring-2021-1.5964491) temporarily, for the next 5-6 weeks I believe and that despite the numbers being on a regular upward trend in the last month.

The rationale is that it is an important time for a number of religions (such as Easter).

The impetus would seem to be the frequents [protests](https://www.castanet.net/news/Kelowna/327884/Protesters-against-in-person-church-service-ban-lined-Hwy-97-Sunday) around religious restrictions and civil disobedience ([holding masses](https://www.theprogress.com/news/as-many-as-19-fraser-valley-churches-have-defied-a-covid-related-ban-on-in-person-worship/)) by a small number of churches in the Kelowna and Fraser Valley regions - areas which coincidentally which have some of the highest case loads.

There was already a [court ruling](https://nationalpost.com/news/canada/b-c-court-upholds-rules-on-religious-gatherings) that the government response to the pandemic, shutting down in person attendance for religious functions, was in the public interest, proportionate to the emergency and therefore did not unduly infringe the charter's right to religious liberty.

So it certainly wasn't a legal obligation.  And it is happening during a time of *increasing* Covid numbers, rather than at a time where better conditions might justify relaxing some restrictions.

(It is quite possible that this planned loosening up will be halted before it begins, as the numbers have been trending up quite uncomfortably since this announcement was first made).

But it does seem like giving in to a vocal minority's pressure. I want to stress that the vast majority of churches and religious people have acted sensibly in the matter and respected the safety of others.